# How to execute main form button function to second form?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a function in a button of main form which start the camera when click, I want that start function to also execute in second form that function contains conditional statement if and else. Usually I make a `public void Name` and put the function inside after that I make a constructor in second form to call that function but this time it doesn't work. How do you do the other way?

```
  public void startProg()
        {
            if (start.Text == "&Start")
            {
                if (DeviceExist)
                {
                    videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                    videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
                    CloseVideoSource();
                    videoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(1366, 768);
                    //videoSource.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
                    videoSource.Start();
                    lblCam.Text = "Device running...";
                    start.Text = "&Stop";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblCam.Text = "Error: No Device selected.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (videoSource.IsRunning)
                {
                    CloseVideoSource();
                    lblCam.Text = "Device stopped.";
                    start.Text = "&Start";
                }
            }
        }

   private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              startProg();
        }
```

In second form

```
 private void Close(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            frmMain main = new frmMain();
main.startProg();
        }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using C# windows form c#

Comment: Yes code because the question is a bit unclear

Comment: Can you add some code that explains what you're doing and what you want to do?

Comment: OK i will add the code

Comment: Don't create a new frmMain! You need to communicate between the forms by methods and events (see answer).

Answer (score 2):

Although you did not point out why it "doesn't work" or how it fails, I'd recommend to create an event in the second form which the first form subscribes to (see [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).
As soon as you fire the event in the second form, the first form could execute the very same action as it would when you press the button.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you simply need a `static` class and method to do this -it's not something that requires state I'm sure, so place the actual API calls to start the camera in a class like this:

```
public static class Camera
{
    public static void Start() { ... }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
Camera.Start();
```

from both forms.

Comment: but I have a comboBox and puting static class wont work because comboBox does not require a static class.

Comment: @user2262382, you said you're starting a camera right? Put the code that starts the camera into the static class. If this isn't what you're doing you **really need to clarify.** See, you can call this method -which starts the camera -from anywhere, and so it doesn't matter if it's a button event or a combo box event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing the Method to launch the camera from form1 to form2.

I've made a very simple example therefor.

The code for the first form is:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Click += delegate { ShowMessageBoxFromForm1(); };
    this.button2.Click += delegate
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(ShowMessageBoxFromForm1);
            form2.ShowDialog();
        };
}

private void ShowMessageBoxFromForm1()
{
    MessageBox.Show("I'm in Form1");
}
```

There are only two buttons on the Form1.

The code for the second form (Form2) is:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   private readonly Action action;
   public Form2(Action action)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.action = action;
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.action.Invoke();
   }
}
```

There's only one button on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some function on multiple forms you should rather write function in separate class. And using the object of that class you should invoke the function.

But if you still want to proceed by your way, try following

Create object of 1st Form on which StartCamera() method is written. Make sure that ,the StartCamera() method is public. Now on second form:

```
Form1 frmObj=new Form1();
frmObj.StartCamera();
```